# ylabel using function subplots in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I recently found the function subplots, which seems to be a more elegant way of setting up multiple subplots than subplot.  However, I don't seem to be able to be able to change the properties of the axes for each subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as npx = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

for i in range(10):
    axes[0].plot(x, i * (x - 10)**2)
    plt.ylabel('plot 1')

for i in range(10):
    axes[1].plot(x, i * np.cos(x))
    plt.ylabel('plot 2')

plt.show()
```

Only the ylabel for the last plot is shown.  The same happens for xlabel, xlim and ylim.

I realise that the point of using subplots is to create common layouts of subplots, but if sharex and sharey are set to false, then shouldn't I be able to change some parameters?

One solution would be to use the subplot function instead, but do I need to do this?

Comment: You probably want to move your `plt.ylabel` calls outside of your loops. They are all the same and only need to be called once per subplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** you *probably* want to use the individual subplot instances.

As you've found, `plt.ylabel` sets the ylabel of the last active plot. To change the parameters of an individual `Axes`, i.e. subplot, you can use [any one of the available methods](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#module-matplotlib.axes). To change the ylabel, you can use `axes[0].set_ylabel('plot 1')`.

`pyplot`, or `plt` as you've defined it, is a helper module for quickly accessing `Axes` and `Figure` methods without needing to store these objects in variables. As the [documentation states](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot):

> [Pyplot p]rovides a MATLAB-like plotting framework.

You can still use this interface, but you will need to adjust which `Axes` is the currently active `Axes`. To do this, `pyplot` has an [`axes(h)`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes) method, where `h` is an instance of an `Axes`. So in you're example, you would call `plt.axes(axes[0])` to set the first subplot active, then `plt.axes(axes[1])` to set the other.